# Tkinter combobox display only specific values of a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python list of tuple I would like to display in a Tkinter combobox.

I just need to display the 1st value of each tuple, that is : 'Saint Sushi', 'Aime Sushi' and 'SoZo Sushi', not entire tuple, without success

```
liste = [('Saint Sushi', '424 Duluth'),
         ("Aime Sushi", '4108 St Denis'),
         ('SoZo Sushi', '4118 St Denis')]

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x300')

def action(event):
    select = listeCombo.get()
    print ('votre selection :', select)


labelChoix = tk.Label(root, text='Choix du lieu')
labelChoix.pack()

#I tried to modify the "values= liste" below with to access liste[0] of each tuple,
#but it does not work
listeCombo = ttk.Combobox(root, values = liste)
listeCombo.current(0)
listeCombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', action)
listeCombo.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please create a [mcve] rather than disjointed blocks of code.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `values=liste` to `values=[x[0] for x in liste]`.